# How to install Visual Studio 2010 (v100) platform toolset on Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

I recently install Windows 10 and I have to build some applications who are using Visual Studio 2010 (v100) platform toolset. Unfortunately, on the properties page of my project, it's written the toolkit is not installed.

I tried to modify my installation of Visual Studio 2017 but I didn't find the v100 toolset.

Where can I find the Visual Studio 2010 platform toolset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. I'm not sure it's the only way to do it but it works. The idea is to install Visual Studio 2010. Because the toolset is provided with it, it installs it on the system and it's possible to use it with Visual Studio 2017.

To download Visual Studio 2010, you have to subscribe (for free) to [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/dev-essentials/) and download [the version of Visual Studio](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202010&pgroup=) you need.

Comment: Seems like it might be called "[Trial] Visual Studio Test Professional 2010" now