# How to install Visual Studio 2010 (v100) platform toolset on VIsual Studio 2019 Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Project on what I must work need platform Visual Studio 2010 (v100) platform toolset but in Visual Installer I don't see this. How can I install this to VS 2019?

Comment: You could install Visual Studio 2010, as suggested in this other, nearly identical (VS2017 instead of VS2019) to yours, SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54554748/260313

Comment: I must download Visual Studio 2010 Express?

Comment: I would try downloading and installing whatever free Visual Studio 2010 version I could find.